# Division in tuple relational calculus

Tags: database-theory, relational-calculus, tuple-relational-calculus

$ \newcommand{\Set}[2]{%
  \{\, #1 \mid #2 \, \}%
}$

I've been trying to find how to express relational division operation in tuple relational calculus. The only thing I found is [this presentation](https://www2.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/354/louie/Equiv_Notations.pdf) where on the page 4 it is said that for relations $R = (A, B)$ and $S = (B)$ the division is

$$
R \div S \equiv \Set{t}{\exists p \; \forall q \; (R(p) \land S(q) \land (p.B = q.B \Rightarrow t.A = p.A))}.
$$

Which I find to be completely wrong. Let me first show why I think it's wrong and then propose my own solution.

Let's have tables

[image]

We want to find movies in which all actors played - meaning $\mathrm{CAST} \div \mathrm{ACTORS}$. Correct solution is a relation with only one attribute: $(\mathrm{Babel})$.

If we followed the given interpretation we would quickly run into a problem.

Let $t = (\mathrm{Seven})$ in the first table. We test whether we can find a $p$ from $\mathrm{CAST}$ such that ${(p.\mathrm{name} = q.\mathrm{name} \land p.\mathrm{surname} = q.\mathrm{surname}) \Rightarrow t.\mathrm{title} = p.\mathrm{title}}$ for all $q$'s from $\mathrm{ACTORS}$.

Let $p = (Seven, Brad, Pitt)$ and let's try all the $q$'s:

1. For $q = (Brad, Pitt)$ we get $true \Rightarrow true$ which is $true$.
2. For $q = (Peter, Wight)$ we get $false \Rightarrow true$ giving $true$.

So the $t = (Seven)$ will appear in the resulting relation even though it's the incorrect tuple (i found a $p$ such that for all the $q's$ the condition is satisfied).

I first tried to convert the relational algebra equivalent
$$
    E_{R} \times E_{S} = \Pi_{A}(E_{R}) \setminus \Pi_{A}((\Pi_{A}(E_{R}) \times E_{S}) \setminus E_{R}),
$$
but it resulted in an extremely complicated result with 4 bound variables so I ruled that way out as well.

The last thing I resorted to is my intuition. Not only was the implication wrong in the aformentioned formula but also the order of quantifiers - for a given $t$ there cannot be a single $p$ such that $p.B = q.B$ for multiple $q$'s at the same time since the $\mathrm{Actors}$ relation cannot contain duplicit tuples.

My shot at this:

We want to find all tuples $t$ from the $\mathrm{CAST}$ such that for every $q$ from $\mathrm{ACTORS}$ I can find a $p$ in the $\mathrm{CAST}$ having the same $\mathrm{name}$ and $\mathrm{surname}$:
\begin{align}
\begin{gathered}
\Set{t}{\forall q \; \exists p \; (\mathrm{ACTORS}(q) \land \mathrm{CAST}(p)  \, \land \\
p.\mathrm{name} = q.\mathrm{name} \land p.\mathrm{surname} = q.\mathrm{surname} \land t.\mathrm{title} = p.\mathrm{title}))}
\end{gathered}
\end{align}
Is that correct?

Comment: I think that your formula should say $ACTORS(q) \implies CAST(p) ...$ rather than $ACTORS(q) \land CAST(p) ...$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. I later found out that it's the same reasoning as in predicate logic where if you say that all humans are mortal, you write $\forall x (\mathrm{Human}(x) \implies \mathrm{Mortal}(x)) $ instead of  $\forall x (\mathrm{Human}(x) \land \mathrm{Mortal}(x)) $ but I can't really explain it well in terms of TRC. I managed to find this - https://cs.ulb.ac.be/public/_media/teaching/infoh303/calculnotes.pdf where they talk about it on page 24.